# Pickle object with very different size in disk compared to size in memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-io, pickle

**Problem Description:**

I am having performance issues with a piece of code that I am writing, and I noticed a very weird behavior of `pickle` that might have something to do with it.

I am saving a really simple `dict` to disk using `pickle` to retrieve it later.

This dictionary is created through a lot of iterations. And it looks like this:

```
{'start_date': Timestamp('2007-09-07 05:42:00'),
 'timeFunction': <bound method Extremist.get_hour of <observer.extremist.Extremist object at 0x000001FADD41EC88>>,
 'timeReference': None, 'min': None, 'max': None}
```

The saved file has `5.863kb` on disk, which is completely absurd as it is a really simple dictionary, when I load it and use the `sys.getsizeof()` method to check the size of the object I loaded with pickle (which has `5.863kb` on disk) it shows me a value of `240` (bytes), which is inline with the amount of data the object holds.

The pickle object seems to grow in size according to the number of iterations my code does. I saw some of these `pickle` objects with more than `10mb` after a larger number of iterations.

**Code that saves the dictionary**

```
try:
    os.remove('data/observer_states/' + obs_id + '.pkl')
except:
    pass

with open('data/observer_states/' + obs_id + '.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(observer_state, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

**Attempted Solution**

I did try to use `os.remove()` a prior `pickle` file instead of just overwriting it. This approach didn't work and I don't have much of a clue on how to deal with this.

**Desired Result**

I want to save this simple `dictionary` to disk without having it occupy `5.863kb` of memory, and understand why is it happening so I can better debug the performance issues I am currently having.

Comment: How's the code that saves the dictionary?

Comment: @Alfabravo I edited the original post and added the code that saves the dict. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: `sys.getsizeof()` **only gives you the size of the dictionary itself, not the size of the objects contained in the dictionary, nor any objects on those objects**

Comment: @juanpa thanks, from the dict the ony object that makes sense in my head to be possible to store lots of data is `<bound method Extremist.get_hour of <observer.extremist.Extremist object at 0x000001FADD41EC88>>` the only thing is that it doesn't store any variables, it just stores a method that doesn't store any variables itself. 

The object that contains this method stores a lot of variables that can be quite big in size, could this be it?

Comment: @joaoavf quite possibly, pickling bound-method objects is a rather new thing, I'm not sure how it is accomplished, but certainly that could get messy I imagine.

Comment: @juanpa the issue was indeed the bound-method object. I replaced it and the pickle sizes are really small as they should be. Thank you.